# TransforMiiX (XML/XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt

If you have a look at [www.PollDaddy.com](http://www.polldaddy.com) you will see that for every question you add a resulting xml and xslt file are requested and when recieved they are transformed.

Then when you save your page you will see that the adjusted xml file (your filled in question data) is send back to the server to be saved to the database.

I would like to make something similar like this technique but I cannot get my transformed xml to html back to its original xml format with adjusted data. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Are you generating XHTML or vanilla HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PollDaddy, but my guess is that they are not actually storing XML in the database. Most likely, it is being generated server-side for every request. The process would look something like this:

1. Browser requests a specific question
2. Server retrieves question detials from database
3. Server generates XML based on question data
4. Server responds with XML and XSLT
5. User answers question
6. Browser posts raw answer data to server
7. Server updates database with answer data
8. Server generates XML based on question/answer data
9. Server responds with XML and XSLT

It would be very inefficient to transform HTML to XML and push that up with requests.